# Synchronisation of Owncloud 8.1 with Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, owncloud, lightning, thunderbird-lightning

Since the migration to Owncloud 8.1 I'm not able to access shared calendar in Lightning.

Real calendar is available, but "shared with me calendar" not !

Here is a quick and dirty hack to solve this. Just modify :

3rdparty/sabre/dav/lib/DAVACL/Plugin.php

Search for the checkPrivileges function, and replace the *if* in the *foreach* by this one :

```
    foreach($privileges as $priv) {

        if (!in_array($priv, $acl) and $priv != '{DAV:}read') {
            $failed[] = $priv;
        }

    }
```

And it's working again !

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's not a question, but a solution I took some time to find. So I shared it

Comment: Can you post some logs about what happens in Lightning without the hack? I'd be interested in solving this without changing sabredav. Same steps to enable debugging as here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:GDATA_Provider#Enabling_Debugging